# Excel to Outlook VBA pre-written body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an ever changing inventory list (new additions made frequently) for which I am attempting to write a sub that will work with Outlook to send a pre-written e-mail response.  From information that I have found online (such as Ron de Bruin's helpful expertise) it seems that this should be possible, but I am stuck at trying to figure out if it is possible to execute the code whenever the e-mail hyperlink is clicked within Column H.

For example, I have a person's first name in Column A starting in row 3, and their e-mail in Column H starting in row 3 which automatically formats as a hyperlink that opens a new, blank message in Outlook.  I wanted to see if it was possible to apply a macro that will auto-populate a Subject line and Body message every time a hyperlink is selected.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim olApplication As Outlook.Application

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olMail.To=
    olMail.Subject = "Subject Line"
    olMail.Body = "This is the body of the e-mail"
    olMail.Display

End Sub
```

What I have is not workable so far because I am not sure if I need to reference the ".To=" field as a range (Column H) or if I need to stick a conditional statement in there to run based on when a cell's hyperlink is selected.

Comment: H3.value should work for a to field.

Comment: if they click on a hyperlink in a cell then it makes that cell the ActiveCell.  you now have a starting point for getting the other data.

Comment: Since a hyperlink will typically launch a web browser or email application, and you want to capture/redirect that action, you may want to explore this:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5c5f7698-dae5-4d9b-8f24-62090425e7cf/can-a-hyperlink-execute-a-vba-macro?forum=exceldev

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.  If I wanted to make the action a worksheet event, what is the equation for making a hyperlink selection an event? When I have tried to decode a way for this using the recording tool, it does not record anything when I select the hyperlinked e-mail.

Comment: My code is not returning any errors, but does not seem to make any of the desired changes:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes.
What you need to do is get hold of the recently opened *Inspector Object* in Outlook.
Remember, when you click on the link, it will automatically create a MailItem.
You need to get hold of that newly created MailItem object for you to manipulate it.

Something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    On Error GoTo halt
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

    Do While olApp.Inspectors.Count = 0
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set olMail = olApp.Inspectors.Item(1).CurrentItem
    With olMail
        .Subject = "I was able to change the subject"
        .Body = "Dear " & Target.Range.Offset(0, -1).Value
        .Display
    End With
forward:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
halt:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume forward
End Sub
```

Take note that you need to bind *Outlook* to *Excel* by referencing it correctly.
Also take note the Outlook should be open otherwise you need to add a handler.
This just points out on how you'll get hold of the newly created mailitem upon following the hyperlink. HTH

Comment: Thank you, L42! That worked wonderfully.  If I wanted to include cell references to other cells within the active cell row (whichever email hyperlink is selected), is that a possibility to include within this sub?

Comment: @user3794203 what do you mean? I didn't follow. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry that was so vague. If I wanted to include cell references from the same row within the spreadsheet that contained the hyperlink that I had just selected, and include the references within the ".Body" section, is that possible?  For instance instead of the text in .Body now, if I had selected the hyperlink from Column B and I had the client's first name in Column A, would I be able to do a .Body message like: "Dear Active.Selection("A"), ..."?